# How to install PHP 7 on EC2 t2.micro Instance running Amazon Linux Distro

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation-package

I want to install the latest PHP 7.0 on an AWS EC2 T2.Micro Instance. So far I have read that currently AWS do not support PHP 7. But hey.. This is just a virtual server in the cloud with me having the full control over its configuration, so there must be some way to get PHP 7 running on this one.

Any help much appreciated.

My box is as below

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
---------------------------------------
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="[*not significant*]"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09

$ uname -a
---------------------------------------
Linux ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 #1 [date] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ uname -mrs
---------------------------------------
Linux 4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64

$ cat /proc/version
---------------------------------------
Linux version 4.1.13-18.26.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-64010) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) )
```

Comment: Any chance you could accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 71):

You can now use the official php7 packages. Here an easy to follow guide.

**1. Install Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0 on Amazon Linux AMI**

```
# Remove current apache & php 
sudo yum remove httpd* php*

# Install Apache 2.4
sudo yum install httpd24

# Install PHP 7.0 
# automatically includes php70-cli php70-common php70-json php70-process php70-xml
sudo yum install php70

# Install additional commonly used php packages
sudo yum install php70-gd
sudo yum install php70-imap
sudo yum install php70-mbstring
sudo yum install php70-mysqlnd
sudo yum install php70-opcache
sudo yum install php70-pdo
sudo yum install php70-pecl-apcu
```

**2. Modify DirectoryIndex to include index.php**

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

find this:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

and modify it to look like this:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

If a directory contains an index.html and an index.php, the server will serve the index.html with this setup. If you do not want that to happen, you have the following options:

Reverse the order, so **index.php** is served when both files exist:

```
 <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
 </IfModule>
```

Only use index.php as the DirectoryIndex:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

**3. Start the Apache web server**

```
sudo service httpd start
```

**4. Configure the Apache web server to start at each system boot**

```
sudo chkconfig httpd on
```

**5. Test your installation**

Create phpinfo.php:

```
echo '<?php print phpinfo();' | sudo tee --append /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

Open your browser and enter your instance's public IP in the address bar followed by /phpinfo.php

```
Example: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/phpinfo.php
```

**Note:** Don't forget to allow incoming connections for HTTP (port 80) in the **Security Groups** of your instance, else your request will time out.

Comment: No, `?>` is only required, if you add further html code after the PHP code. One reason I never end a file containing php with `?>` is that it won't add accidental empty lines to the final html.

Comment: I was wondering about that because I was having issues getting phpinfo() to work. It turned out that I had to re-install Apache and PHP 7. Thanks!

Comment: Hello guys, em getting his error: No package httpd24 available.

Comment: After running these commands, I had to do yum remove php5* to force remove it and only then everything started to work. Otherwise yum remove php* was not removing it, causing no php to work.

Comment: Worked great. FYI you can use php71 now.

Comment: Thanks, worked like charm :). Yes, do yum remove php7* instead of php*

Answer (score 34):

I got this running on my instance. You need http2.2 for it to work with the webtatic repo.  I had so many repos there were a bunch of different version incompatibilities.  I didn't keep great notes but looking at my history I basically did this:

```
# Remove current php & apache
sudo service httpd stop
sudo yum remove httpd* php* 

# Remove any third party repos that aren't relevant
sudo yum repolist
sudo yum remove remi-safe

# Install Standard Apache for Amazon AMI
sudo yum install httpd   #specify http22 if you get a different version

# Download webtatic
mkdir -p /tmp/php7
cd /tmp/php7
wget https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

# Install webtatic repo
sudo yum install latest.rpm
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo  'set repo enables
sudo yum clean all

# Install base php7
sudo yum install --enablerepo=webtatic php70w
php -v   #Should say something like  PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2016 16:09:32) ( NTS )
sudo yum install php70w-opcache
sudo yum install php70w-xml
sudo yum install php70w-pdo
sudo yum install php70w-mysqlnd
sudo yum install php70w-gd
sudo yum install php70w-apcu
sudo yum install php70w-pecl-apcu
sudo yum install php70w-mbstring
sudo yum install php70w-imap

# Restart apache
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: This answer works great doing this after I used CloudFormation to quickly get a site up for a php7 testing platform. The other answers did not work in my case, but rather they caused apache (httpd) to not see php at all.

Answer (score 32):

Current answer to problem (not original version in question) - worth knowing since this is a bit simpler and php7 isn't available in the standard repos for Amazon Linux 2, and this didn't come up until I searched a bit harder:

```
amazon-linux-extras install php7.2
```

The version of extras can be checked with a list command if v7.2 is no longer current:

```
amazon-linux-extras list
```

Answer (score 13):

There are now official php7 packages for aws linux as of July 14, 2016. See the announcement at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3902

> To list available packages, run yum list php70*

Comment: For me it seamed to work after I enabled the "amzn-updates" repo in yum

Answer (score 10):

The other answers seem to only work with Apache 2.2 but not 2.4.

Here's how I installed php7 on Amazon Linux running Apache 2.4:

First, if php is already installed, then remove it:

```
sudo yum remove php5*
```

Take note of the php5 packages that are being removed as you'll need to install the php7 versions of them. The php7 package names have a fairly direct and unambiguous mapping from their php5 counterparts as you'll see below. The rest of the instructions cover a classic LAMP stack and may be sufficient for your use-case.

Using instructions from http://www.spidersoft.com.au/2015/php-7-on-ami-linux-ec2/

```
wget http://mirrors.mediatemple.net/remi/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo yum install remi-release-6.rpm
```

edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and set `enabled=1`

```
sudo yum upgrade -y
sudo yum install php70 php70-php-fpm php70-php-xml php70-php-pdo php70-php-mysqlnd php70-php-gd php70-php-pecl-apcu php70-php-mbstring php70-php-mcrypt php70-php-opcache
```

Now you should have php70-php-fpm installed, which you can use in conjunction with apache:

Start the fpm daemon:

```
sudo service php70-php-fpm start
```

Switch Apache from prefork to mpm event worker (this is required because mod_php isn't thread safe) in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`:

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

Instruct apache to pass all php requests to php-fpm by adding the following lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
```

Restart apache using `sudo service httpd restart`. If everything went ok you should be able to verify the installation by requesting a php file containing `phpinfo()`.

If you have existing shell scripts that use php's cli interpreter and thus start with `#!/usr/bin/php`, you have to set up a symlink to `/usr/bin/php` since the binary is now named `/usr/bin/php70`. You can do this as follows:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php70 /usr/bin/php
```

For more info on how to configure php-fpm see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

Comment: Small notices: use "service php70-php-fpm ..." command instead. ProxyPassMatch works with Apache 2.2 (with mod_proxy_fcgi in EPEL), and Apache 2.4, but with the latest, it's simpler to use SetHandler to proxy.

Answer (score 10):

I was installing PHP 7.0 on a production box that already has apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5. I wanted to install PHP 7.0 alongside it in a way that would have no Server outage. This is what I did.

```
# Install PHP 7.0 
# automatically includes php70-cli php70-common php70-json php70-process php70-xml
sudo yum install php70

# Install additional commonly used php packages
sudo yum install php70-gd
sudo yum install php70-imap
sudo yum install php70-mbstring
sudo yum install php70-mysqlnd
sudo yum install php70-opcache
sudo yum install php70-pecl-apcu
```

This happily installed PHP 7 alongside PHP 5.5. The trick was to tell apache to use 7.0. I'm not sure if this was the best way, but I achieved this by changing these 2 permalinks:

```
ln -sf /etc/httpd/conf.d/php-conf.7.0 /etc/alternatives/php.conf
ln -sf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php-conf.7.0 /etc/alternatives/10-php.conf
```

At this point apache is still happily running 5.5. Then when you restart apache it *should* be working with 7.0 (maybe 7.0.1). This is the no downtime way. I'd still recommend doing what I did, which is to rebuild PROD on another instance  (create a TEST server) and test it all once before actually doing it on PROD. Good luck!

Oh, and right now the **php** command will still run 5.5. You can either change any scripts or CRON jobs to point to php7 or change the default version by running

```
alternatives --config php
```

Comment: These steps can also be followed for upgrading to 7.1 (which is now available) by changing any php70 to php71 (7.0 to 7.1)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm for php72.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. Just:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y php7.2
```

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

can follow this step-by-step guide for LAMP installation

```
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd

sudo service httpd start
```

Comment: Loaded plugins: langpacks, update-motd
No package httpd24 available.
No package php70 available.
No package mysql56-server available.
No package php70-mysqlnd available.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick copy-paste install:

```
wget http://mirrors.mediatemple.net/remi/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo yum install -y remi-release-6.rpm
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y --enablerepo=epel php70
```

Test with:

```
php70 -v
```

And if you want the executable to be `php`:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php70 /usr/local/bin/php 
php -v
```

Comment: For me, Apache is not executing PHP, it shows phpcode

Answer (score 2):

This thread helped me get close enough to finish it off, I'm sharing the commands and output that worked for me.

On **[Amazon Lightsail](https://amazonlightsail.com/)** with Amazon Linux (**amzn1.x86_64**), the following command list helped me **rid the system of Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 to get to Apache 2.4 and PHP**:

1. Remove the current version of php and related tools:

> `sudo yum remove php*`

```
==============================================================================================================================================
Package                           Arch                        Version                                  Repository                       Size
==============================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 php                               x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      7.4 M
 php-cli                           x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      6.4 M
 php-common                        x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      6.3 M
 php-devel                         x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      9.9 M
 php-gd                            x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      669 k
 php-mbstring                      x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      4.1 M
 php-mcrypt                        x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                       92 k
 php-mysql                         x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      445 k
 php-pdo                           x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      381 k
 php-xml                           x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1                         @amzn-main                      625 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================
Remove  10 Packages
```

2. Remove the current version of Apache (*note you should backup your `conf` and `conf.d` folder before doing this, imho; in my case, it was a new system setup so there was nothing of interest there*):

> `sudo yum remove http*`

```
==============================================================================================================================================
 Package                           Arch                         Version                                Repository                        Size
==============================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 httpd                             x86_64                       2.2.31-1.8.amzn1                       @amzn-main                       3.0 M
 httpd-devel                       x86_64                       2.2.31-1.8.amzn1                       @amzn-main                       534 k
 httpd-tools                       x86_64                       2.2.31-1.8.amzn1                       @amzn-main                       135 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================
Remove  3 Packages
```

3. Install Apache 2.4 (and start Apache)

> `sudo yum install httpd24.x86_64`
>
> `sudo service httpd start`

4. Install PHP 7

> `sudo yum install php70`

```
==============================================================================================================================================
 Package                           Arch                       Version                                  Repository                        Size
==============================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php70                             x86_64                     7.0.13-1.19.amzn1                        amzn-updates                     3.3 M
Installing for dependencies:
 php70-cli                         x86_64                     7.0.13-1.19.amzn1                        amzn-updates                     4.7 M
 php70-common                      x86_64                     7.0.13-1.19.amzn1                        amzn-updates                     1.2 M
 php70-json                        x86_64                     7.0.13-1.19.amzn1                        amzn-updates                      65 k
 php70-process                     x86_64                     7.0.13-1.19.amzn1                        amzn-updates                      79 k
 php70-xml                         x86_64                     7.0.13-1.19.amzn1                        amzn-updates                     309 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+5 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 9.6 M
Installed size: 31 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/6): php70-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                              | 3.3 MB     00:00
(2/6): php70-cli-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                          | 4.7 MB     00:00
(3/6): php70-common-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                       | 1.2 MB     00:00
(4/6): php70-json-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                         |  65 kB     00:00
(5/6): php70-process-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                      |  79 kB     00:00
(6/6): php70-xml-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                          | 309 kB     00:00
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                          14 MB/s | 9.6 MB  00:00:00
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : php70-json-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                        1/6
  Installing : php70-process-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                     2/6
  Installing : php70-xml-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                         3/6
  Installing : php70-cli-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                         4/6
  Installing : php70-common-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                      5/6
  Installing : php70-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                             6/6
  Verifying  : php70-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                             1/6
  Verifying  : php70-common-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                      2/6
  Verifying  : php70-json-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                        3/6
  Verifying  : php70-process-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                     4/6
  Verifying  : php70-xml-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                         5/6
  Verifying  : php70-cli-7.0.13-1.19.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                         6/6

Installed:
  php70.x86_64 0:7.0.13-1.19.amzn1

Dependency Installed:
  php70-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.13-1.19.amzn1            php70-common.x86_64 0:7.0.13-1.19.amzn1        php70-json.x86_64 0:7.0.13-1.19.amzn1
  php70-process.x86_64 0:7.0.13-1.19.amzn1        php70-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.13-1.19.amzn1

Complete!
```

Comment: i'd make this because I like run only official repositories.

Comment: it does not let php execute by Apache

Answer (score 1):

The php 7 package name is **php70w**. So what you can do is, install a Webtatic repo on you linux machine and install it from there.

```
rpm -ivh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum clean all
yum install --enablerepo=webtatic php70w
```

Comment: I tried that one. It gives me this... --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php70w-7.0.2-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
           Installed: httpd-2.2.31-1.6.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Available: httpd24-2.4.16-1.62.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
           Available: httpd24-2.4.16-1.63.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211

Comment: Now these are some dependencies error that you have to install manually. Check the package version and configure

Comment: @Siddharthsharma I tried this, it worked for apache but on CLI it says `php not found`

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l $(which php)`

Answer (score 1):

By default, just few Yum Repo is enabled on RedHat EC2.
To enable all, just type

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-*
```

and do a yum list now, you should be able to see this:

yum list |grep php7

Answer (score 0):

Several answers should work here; however, when I was installing mine, it would not render pages and would display text instead of rendered PHP.

To fix that, I ran

`sudo yum install php70-php-fpm`

After that, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I installed PHP 7.1 on Amazon Linux:

```
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6.rpm epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71

wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/s/scl-utils-20120229-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh scl-utils-20120229-1.el6.x86_64.rpm 

yum install php71
```

https://gist.github.com/ihor/581d169886c29e7e17d01b0041167b01

Comment: "php71" is the SCL available in "remi-safe", you only need to enable the "remi-php71" repository if you want the base packages. See https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Right, haven't noticed that. The problem was that for some reason I couldn't install ```scl-utils``` from the available repos.

Comment: `wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/epel/6/x86_64/scl-utils-20120229-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` 

should be changed to 

`wget ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/s/scl-utils-20120229-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`