# How to install PHP 7.1 on EC2 running on Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03 having nginx as web server?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, php-7.1, amazon-linux

How to install PHP 7.1 on Amazon EC2 t2.micro Instance running `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03` having nginx as web server?

[Reference to PHP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873685/how-to-install-php-7-on-ec2-t2-micro-instance-running-amazon-linux-distro)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed below steps to install **PHP7.1** which had already **Nginx as web server** for **Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03**

```
#Remove Old PHP
yum remove php*

#Update Reposistory
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm

#Update Amazon AMI
yum upgrade -y

#Install PHP
#List of PHP packages https://webtatic.com/packages/php71/

yum install php71w php71w-cli  php71w-fpm
yum install php71w-mysql php71w-xml php71w-curl
yum install php71w-opcache php71w-pdo php71w-gd
yum install php71w-pecl-apcu php71w-mbstring php71w-imap
yum install php71w-pecl-redis php71w-mcrypt

#change listen mode to CGI
sed -i 's/127.0.0.1:9000/\/tmp\/php5-fpm.sock/g' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
touch /tmp/php5-fpm.sock
chmod 777 /tmp/php5-fpm.sock
service nginx restart
```

> The reason I am still using /tmp/php5-fpm.sock file so that I do not need to change PHP7 sock file in all website nginx conf and assuming server do not have PHP5 as as on first step it has been removed.

Comment: Awesome instruction! It worked on my EC2 AWS (AMI Linux). However instead of changing `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I changed `/etc/nginx/conf.d/my-site.conf` option `fastcgi_pass` to `127.0.0.1:9000` (so that it looks `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`)

Answer (score 19):

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40581436/8255629) answer, change Step 1 to the following:

**1. Install Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.1 on Amazon Linux AMI**

```
# Remove current apache & php 
sudo yum remove httpd* php*

# Install Apache 2.4
sudo yum install httpd24

# Install PHP 7.1
sudo yum install php71

# Install additional commonly used php packages
sudo yum install php71-gd
sudo yum install php71-imap
sudo yum install php71-mbstring
sudo yum install php71-mysqlnd
sudo yum install php71-opcache
sudo yum install php71-pdo
sudo yum install php71-pecl-apcu
```

Basically replacing php70 with php71.

**Continue with step 2 and the rest as per the [original tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40581436/8255629).**

Comment: For some reason I had to specifically remove PHP 7 to get PHP 7.1 to work by doing sudo yum remove php7*

Answer (score 6):

A reliable way to achieve the same output is by following commands on **Amazon Linux AMI 2**.

```
# Remove current php & apache
sudo service httpd stop
sudo yum remove httpd* php*

sudo yum install httpd

amazon-linux-extras install php7.1
```

Comment: Will try and see if `amazon-linux-extras` works, thanks

Comment: Yes, recently added feature - please try and enjoy the result.

Comment: It has pre defind extenstions not all, Like what I have written, in my answer are not fully avilable.