# How can i downgrade the PHP 7.2.xx version to 7.1.XX or 7.0.xx on EC2 Linux 2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, lamp

I am new to EC2. I have installed the latest php version which 7.2.22 . But my php files are in supported in latest version. So whether running the file in php in ec2 linux 2 its not working. So i have decide to downgrade php 7.2 to php 7.1.xx or php 7.0.xx.

How to Downgrade it. or else How can i uninstall php 7.2.xx and reinstall php 7.1.xx or php 7.0.xx

> Please give the command to better understands and execute the commands to check.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You should consider to update your code to work with PHP 7.2+, because from [official PHP support page](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), security support for 7.1 ends in **1 month** (1 Dec 2019)

Answer (score 0):

I am instructing the command in ubuntu,
Command will differ wrt. to OS

Please purge the 7.2 php than Re-install 7.0 or 7.1

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0-common
```

Install php 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

Install php 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0
```

Hope it helps .....!!!

Comment: I am using putty when i run your first command they give this
$ sudo apt-get purge php7.0-common
sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: @ArslanMaqbool Which OS are you using ?

Comment: i am using amazon linux 2

Comment: @ArslanMaqbool Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873685/how-to-install-php-7-on-ec2-t2-micro-instance-running-amazon-linux-distro
Hope it helps